# Need to scale/translate array of points, so the path will match the given end point

Tags: java, c#, algorithm, geometry

I have an array of points. I'm looking for a way to scale/translate the whole path so the end point of the path will match the end point I give, but keeping the shape of the points array.

```
    void translate(Point[] array, Point scaleToPoint)
```

Is there any algorithm that does what I've described? Thank you in advance, any help is really appreciated!

[image: Image example of what I'm looking for]
[image]

Comment: Is the point array ordered?

Comment: It isn't. The array contains mouse movement points which were recorded by me when I wanted to click some object on screen. What I want to do is when the destination point changes, it uses the same mouse movement data, just translated to the destination point.

Comment: so we're looking for the Point with the max value for `x`?

Comment: I want to translate/scale the whole path, like in the image. When I move the last point in the array, the rest of the points in array should also move like they were scaled.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused as to what you mean. Can you give me another example? Like what happens if the point go back towards the left

Comment: Added second example. So I wanted to move the end point from (50, 200) to (0, 400). When I do that, the other points in path should move according to the end point, so that the path will keep the "shape" it had before.

Comment: Sorry, I've messed the second example. The translated end point should be (0, 400) not (150, 400)

Comment: So its scaling by different ratios in the X and Y? Just making absolutely sure before I post my answer.

Comment: Yes, scalling in both X and Y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following. Instead of considering the starting point as some arbitrary position such as (0, 100), translate it temporarily to the origin (0, 0). Then, calculate the scalar quantities needed to stretch the end point to its new position.

First, we define the following reference points assuming that `array` is non-empty.

```cs
Point start = array[0];
Point end = array[array.Length - 1];
```

Then, calculate the scalars required to stretch the points.

```cs
float sx = (scaleToPoint.X - start.X) / (end.X - start.X);
float sy = (scaleToPoint.Y - start.Y) / (end.Y - start.Y);
```

Finally, perform the actual stretching.

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
  array[i].X = array[i].X + (array[i].X - start.X) * sx;
  array[i].Y = array[i].Y + (array[i].Y - start.Y) * sy;
}
```

You can verify that this works because:

- `array[0]` ends back up where it was initially.
- `array[array.Length - 1]` ends up at `scaleToPoint`.
- The transformation was linear.

Comment: You could use `array[^1]` with C# 8.0 too

Comment: Thank you so much! That what I was looking for.

@Aggragoth thank you too for your time!

Have a nice day guys!